# How can I navigate from code window to variable view eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am debugging my program and I want to see the content of an object but I don't want to look for it in the variable views , I want something that navigate me from the code window to the variable view window
How can I do that ?

Comment: Read the eclipse docs

Comment: I read it and I didn't find !

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the debugger and stopped at a breakpoint you can also simply hover over a variable and a tooltip will appear that will show you the contents of a variable. If you move the cursor into the pop up and click it'll become 'sticky', allowing you to scroll, resize...

You can also select some code snippet (i.e. a method invocation...), right click and select 'Inspect' and you'll get a pop up that will show you the result

Comment: when I hover the mouse on the public field of object I see just the tosting of it and I want to see the content of it (not the tostring) However I can see that in the variable window

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+I

its there under keys preference....